# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\BaseController' not found

Tags: php, laravel

Good day everyone, I'm new to laravel and i'm happy learning it. but i have the error written above. I've searched stackoverflow faqs,devdocs, and others but no way out.  while implementing my controller.
On the controller, i have this codes by default,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controlers;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, AuthorizesResources, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

while in my controller, I have this code written

```
<?php


namespace App\http\Controllers;


class NiceActionController extends Controller
    {
    public function getNiceAction($action, $name = null){
        return view($action, ['name'=> $name]);
    }

    }
```

please how will i rectify the error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you running?

Comment: I am using laravel 5.2

Comment: If you haven't got that far, I'd recommend doing a fresh install of Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

[This is what your Controller should look like](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.2/app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php)

The reason why it's broken is because you - or somebody who's working on this project - removed all of the `use` statements in this class. BaseController exists as a part of Laravel's internal Routing component. The `'App\Http\Controllers\BaseController' not found` error you're seeing is because you're no longer referencing the class properly.

Under app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php, change it back to the following:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesResources;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, AuthorizesResources, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```